# i have a field in the database "tags", i can put like the following: php, laravel, html, css. I need to split the tags variable into an array

Tags: python, django

i have this model :

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    tags = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

this is the view:

```
def homepage(request):
    projects = Projects.objects.filter(status='1').order_by('-listorder')
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'projects': projects})
```

this is where i want to display it in

```
<div class="box-cat-title">{{ project.title }}</div>
<div class="box-cat-content">{{ project.tags }}</div>
```

i need something like that:

```
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="box-cat-title">{{ project.title }}</div>
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <div class="box-cat-content">{{ tags.tag }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% for project in projects %}
```

Comment: You can use `project.tags.split(', ')` to split the string into separate strings, as long as every tag is separate by a comma and a space. This will be different based on your actual needs for how you want the tag string to be input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="box-cat-title">{{ project.title }}</div>
    {% for tag in project.tags.split(',') %}
        <div class="box-cat-content">{{ tag }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```